# Add SessionId to IoTHub messages before sending to a ServiceBus queue

Tags: azure-iot-hub, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We are using IoTHub Routes to direct messages to the ServiceBus queues. One of the queues is `Session` enabled for the sake of ordered message processing.

Is it possible to enrich messages for that particular endpoint and add SessionId to them right in IotHub before directing to the queue? The value for the SessionId is inside the JSON content of the message.

Answer (score 0):

As of writing this, It's not possible to do so. Session enabled queues could be added as an endpoint to IoTHub but then stay Unreachable there.